# How to Update xml values and save that xml in xna 4.0?

Tags: xml-serialization, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xna-4.0

I want to update the values from my xml.I am using LINQ to XML,then using LINQ to XML how to update values from xml? or any other procedure for updating values from xml? and another question is how to save that xml file in xna 4.0?